# Imprimir el contenido de un DIV en PDF

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una aplicacion en la cual genero codigos PDF417, les comento tengo un boton que toma la informacion de un TEXTAREA y con una dll o libreria genera un codigo PDF417, lo que busco es que ese DIV que genera poner un boton para imprimirlo en PDF O WORD o alguna opcion para mandarlas a un pdf acomodado en una cuadricula, para imrprimir las etiquetas.

O en su defecto convertirlo en imagen y exportarlo a pdf o word

```
<div id="barcode"></div>
```

Este es mi div generado, gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar CSS para elegir que elementos imprimiras al ejecutar el evento en el botón.

```
    <style media="print">
        #sidebar, .header, .site-footer, .invoice-btn, #titulo {
            display: none;
        }
        #contenido_DIV {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>

<a onclick="javascript:javascript:window.print();" >Print</a>
```

El único inconveniente que le veo es que tienes que definir bien los selectores para que solo se vea en la ventana de impresión lo que tu deseas ver.

También lo puedes hacer mediante javascript, que creo es lo mejor en tu caso. Mandas llamar la función con el nombre del DIV que quieres imprimir, después abres la ventana de impresión en una pestaña nueva con el contenido del div y al cerrar el cuadro de diálogo se cerrará la pestaña automáticamente.

```
<div id="ID_DIV">

</div>
<a onclick="javascript:window.imprimirDIV('ID_DIV');">Print </a>
<script>
    function imprimirDIV(contenido) {
        var ficha = document.getElementById(contenido);
        var ventanaImpresion = window.open(' ', 'popUp');
        ventanaImpresion.document.write(ficha.innerHTML);
        ventanaImpresion.document.close();
        ventanaImpresion.print();
        ventanaImpresion.close();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomendo la libreria "[html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)"

Haría algo asi:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
    html2canvas($("#barcode"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var win=window.open();
                    win.document.write("<br><img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
                    win.print();
                }
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Ya importe la libreria, aun soy nuevo en javascript, ¿como lo puedo mandar a llamar en un boton?